# selecting data with laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I trying to understand laravel eloquent relationship so i created two tables. structure of tables defined in laravel   migration  is
 for mostpopular table

```
Schema::create('mostpopulars',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('song_id')->unsigned();
        $table->index('song_id');
        $table->foreign('song_id')->references('id')->on('song_details')->delete('cascade');
    });
```

for song_detail table

```
  Schema::create('song_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('song_title');
        $table->string('song_name');
        $table->string('song_album');
        $table->string('song_singer');
        $table->string('song_musicby');
        $table->string('song_location');
        $table->string('song_album_image');
        $table->string('song_language');
        $table->string('song_lyrics',3000);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

then in Mostpopular model defined function for relating two table

```
 public function song_detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Song_detail','id');
}
```

and in controller index function i want to do something like this

```
$songs          = Song_detail::select()->latest()->get();
    $malayalamSongs = Mostpopular::select('song_id')->groupBy('song_id')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 2')->get(); 
   $mp = $malayalamSongs;
    dd($mp->song_detail);
```

but getting error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$Song_detail
```

please help me to find the error and what i am trying to do is get the details of songs from song_details table where `song_id` occurred more than two times `song_id` is in mostpopular tables.

Comment: your song_detail model need need belongto

Comment: ok i added  public function songsdetail()
    {
     return $this->belongTo('App\Mostpoular');
    }

Comment: but i get same error

Comment: ok, you $mp is an array of objects. So you cannot call ->song_detail on the array.

Comment: I make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the eloquent get() will return an array, you cannot call relation method on the array.

you can use first() to replace the get() or

change

```
 $mp = $malayalamSongs;
 dd($mp->song_detail);
```

to

```
   $mp = $malayalamSongs;
   foreach($mp as $v)
   {
     dd($v->song_detail);
   }
```

Comment: sorry blank page is because i removed get() so i put it back but i get null insted of songs details

Comment: make sure the query have results. if not, the rusults is null

Comment: ok now i get the exact output the problem was in  Model Mostpopular is change                                                                                                    public function song_detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Song_detail','id');
}                                                                                                                          public function song_detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Song_detail','id','song_id');
}  and so i got the expected result with your help keep supporting thanks